# creating a non-literal python tuple programmatically

Tags: python, tuples

I want to create a tuple of length m, with a 1 in each position except for one n in position k.

e.g.: m=5, n=7, k=3 should yield `(1,1,1,7,1)` (length 5 with a 7 in position 3)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> m, n, k = 5, 7, 3
>>> tuple(n if i == k else 1 for i in range(m))
(1, 1, 1, 7, 1)
```

Answer (score 10):

First construct a list, then turn it into a tuple if you really need to:

```
def make_tuple(m, n, k):
    a = [1] * m
    a[k] = n
    return tuple(a)
```

Example:

```
>>> make_tuple(m=5, n=7, k=3)
(1, 1, 1, 7, 1)
```

Comment: Foiled again! You beat me to it. OP: Converting to a tuple is _probably_ unnecessary. Is there any reason why a list won't do?

Comment: Not sure, I'm using pylab's `kron(my_tuple, my_matrix)` to repeat rows/columns of a matrix.

Answer (score 8):

```
(1,) * k + (n,) + (1,) * (m-k-1)
```